# Change checked radio button when click another <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried change radio button status, by putting `<select>` to `<label>`, but it didn't worked. I need to change checked radio button, when I click another `<select>`. jQuery or javascript can be used for this task.

```
<html>
<body>
    <label for="0">
        <select id="sorting">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="0" checked> 


    <label for="1">
        <select id="sorting1">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="1">

    <label for="2">
        <select id="sorting2">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="2">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add what you have tried so far in OP

Comment: This code is what I tried.

Comment: @ЦунскийНикита You tried to change something by pure html? And im not even sure what it is that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery you could simply do

```
 $("select").change(function () {
  $(this).next('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', 'checked');
 });
```

**What it does:** If any `select` element is changed, it finds the next input of type radio and checks it.

> Note: You need to remove the `<label>`s from your HTML.

```js
 $("select").change(function () {
  $(this).next('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', 'checked');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sorting">
      <option>0</optiacon>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="0"> 

    <select id="sorting1" name="gender">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="1">

    <select id="sorting2" name="gender">
      <option>0</option>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="2">
```

Comment: Thank You! I will use this!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll("select")
selects.forEach( (select) => select.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
  event
  .target
  .parentElement
  .nextElementSibling.checked = true
))
```

```html
<label for="0">
        <select id="sorting">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="0" checked> 


    <label for="1">
        <select id="sorting1">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="1">

    <label for="2">
        <select id="sorting2">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" id="2">
```